# Создание массива для вызова нужной кнопки и вызова

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

На странице есть несколько новостных видео. Воспроизведение видео во всех блоках производится только то, которое указано в функции (числовое), а необходимо не одно видео везде, а каждому блоку своё. 
Помогите сделать массив, который сможет вызывать необходимый файл для каждого блока

```
`   <div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20">
                                                    <div class="news-prev">
                                                        <div class="news_video" data-ride="carousel">
                                                                                                <div class="carousel" role="listbox">
                                                                                                        <div class="item active">
                                                                                                                <div class="widget-gradient iba">
                                                                                                                </div>
                                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                        <div class="btn-play">
                                                                                                                <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>
                                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                        <h3 class="widget-gradient-title iba">Приветствие и знакомство с тренером</h3>
                                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                        <div class="video-player">
                                                                                                                    <video controls="false">
                                                                                                                            <source src="ISS/Секреты Хакеров! - Часть 1/01 Введение/001 Приветствие и знакомство с тренером.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                                                                                                    </video>
                                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                </div>

                                                        <div class="news-prev-stat"><i class="fa fa-commenting-o"></i>9</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20">
                                                    <div class="news-prev">
                                                        <div class="news_video" class="carousel slide widget-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
                                                                                                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                                                                                        <div class="item active">
                                                                                                                <div class="widget-gradient iba">
                                                                                                                </div>
                                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                        <div class="btn-play">
                                                                                                                <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>
                                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                        <h3 class="widget-gradient-title iba">Небольшой твик для безопасности</h3>
                                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                        <div class="video-player">
                                                                                                            <video controls="false">
                                                                                                                                <source src="ISS/Секреты Хакеров! - Часть 1/01 Введение/002 Небольшой твик для безопасности.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                                                                                                        </video>
                                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                </div>`
```

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.news_video').click(function() {

```
// если блок имеет класс OPEN, тогда ничего не делаем. Иначе -  прорисовка видео

  if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
      return false;
  }
  // document.getElementsByTagName('video')[1].webkitRequestFullScreen();
  // document.getElementsByTagName('video')[1].pause();
  // $(".close-btn.video,  .close-btn.fs").css('transform', 'scale(0)');
  // setTimeout(function() {
  //     $(".close-btn.video, .close-btn.fs").remove();
  // }, 300);


  // прорисовка видео

  var block = $('.news_video')
  var video = $(this).find('.video-player').addClass('open');
  var player= $(this).find('.video-player').find('video');
  block.addClass('open');
  player.attr('width', block.width() + 300);
  player.css('transform', 'translateX(-150px)');
  player.attr('height', block.height());
  $(this).find('video').get(1);
  document.getElementsByTagName('video')[1].controls = false;

  // РАскрытие видео
  $('<div class="close-btn fs"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></div>').appendTo('.news_video').click(function() {
      document.getElementsByTagName('video')[1].webkitRequestFullScreen();
  })

  $('<div class="close-btn video"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></div>').appendTo('.news_video').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      block.removeClass('open');
      video.removeClass('open');
      document.getElementsByTagName('video')[1].pause();
      $(".close-btn.video,  .close-btn.fs").css('transform', 'scale(0)');
      setTimeout(function() {
          $(".close-btn.video, .close-btn.fs").remove();
      }, 300);
  })
  setTimeout(function() {
      $(".close-btn.video, .close-btn.fs").css('transform', 'scale(1)');
  }, 5)
```

})

})

Answer (score 1):

Замените строку

```
var block = $('.news_video')
```

на

```
var block = $(this);
```

P.S. Проявите уважение к тем, к кому Вы обращаетесь за помощью, и отформатируйте код и html.

Comment: Поддерживаю, вы же уже задавали вопрос и вам давали такой ответ..